# Prepare for Segue is never called

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following storyboard:

[Image(Not enough reputation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgXYH.png)

How it works?

1. The user can see all the cell.
2. The user can't look for one specific cell.
3. When a cell is tapped, the table view disappear and the container view is not hidden anymore.
4. The container view display all the information about the objet in the cell pressed.

The Master controller has these methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchBar.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    tableView.isHidden = true
    especificationView.isHidden = false
    print("A")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToEspecification", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("B")
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
        aircraftSelected = aircrafts[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

And the view contended has:

```
func changeLabel(text: String) {
        registrationLabel.text = text
    }

@IBAction func unwindToEspecificationViewController (sender: UIStoryboardSegue) -> Void{
            print("B")
            if let controller = sender.source as? AircraftSelectionViewController, let data = controller.aircraftSelected{
                self.aircraft = data
                changeLabel(text: (aircraft?.registration)!)
            }
        }
```

The master storyboard is linked to the other view whit the following segue and his indentifier:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOtiu.png)

When I execute this code the terminal show just "A".

How I can make it works?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your storyboard, Aircraft Selection is a parent view controller, and Aircraft Especification is its child view controller. There is no "segue" possible between them; they both show their views simultaneously on the screen, so there is nowhere to "go" from here.

If the idea was to display a table view whose cells can be limited by a search, that is not a job for a segue but for a UISearchController architecture.

If the idea is to establish a line of communication from the Aircraft Selection view controller to the Aircraft Especification view controller, the latter is the Aircraft Selection's child, so from Aircraft Selection's point of view, it is `self.childViewControllers[0]` (or, in Swift 4.2, `self.children[0]`). You will need to cast it down with `as!` in order to talk to it as an Aircraft Especification.

Comment: That has sense. How can I implement the same using the search controller? I just need to pass an object to the other view.

Comment: I don't know what "the other view" is. (Or who "I" is, for that matter.) Please use the names of your actual view controllers etc. I know what those mean, because you showed your storyboard.

Comment: From the main view to the view contained in the main view

Comment: Do you mean view _controller_?

Comment: Yes, to the Aircraft selector View Controller to the Aircraft Expecification View Controller (as you can see in the image posted)

Comment: The Aircraft Especification view controller is the Aircraft Selection's child! We've already established that. So from Aircraft Selection's point of view, it is `self.childViewControllers[0]` (or, in Swift 4.2, `self.children[0]`). You will need to cast it down with `as!` in order to talk to it as an Aircraft Especification.

Comment: And how can I access to the self.children[0] functions? self.children[0] as! Aircraft Specification...

Comment: Just call them!

Comment: If you were to change the embed segue to a push, that might accomplish what you're attempting to do with the prepare:forSegue?

Comment: I have tried `self.children[0] as! AircraftEspecificationTableViewController` but it shows a error because: Value of type 'AircraftSelectionViewController' has no member 'children'`

Comment: Because you are not using Swift 4.2. I cannot help you if you do not _read_ what I say.

Comment: Okay sorry, I misunderstand what you say. Many Thanks matt.